# Understanding SetFilter in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I am using Sphinx, but not fully understanding how SetFilter works.  My assumption as of now is that in the Sphinx Config I have my query:

```
 SELECT ID, Kittens, Puppies FROM db_animals;
```

And then I put in the attributes I would like to filter on:

```
 sql_attr_uint = puppies
```

Then when I call Sphinx if I want to filter on one of these attributes I put this:

```
 $cl->SetFilter( 'puppies', array($puppyID));
```

So, if $puppyID = 7

Sphinx will only return rows where the puppies column is set to 7.

Am I interpreting this correctly?  Anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to your first question. And no to the second.

Comment: Thanks Barry!!  Is there a way to test and see if it is working?  For example, I have $cl->SetFilter( 'catID', array($catID));

And $catID is set to 7, so, shouldn't I only be getting items with catID set to 7?  I am getting a couple with catID set to 7, but then a few more with different values.  Seems it shouldn't be doing that if the above is true?

Comment: Sounds like a logic error somewhere else. But cant really help you debug without much more details of the system.